# MenuItem in Compact Framework 3.5

Tags: compact-framework

Is there anyway to programmatically force a MenuItem to raise their popup event?  Basically, if you click on it with your stylus or finger, it shows the MenuItem collection for that specific MenuItem.  I'd like to be able to do by using a button that I capture.

Answer (score 0):

If you add your menu items to a [ContextMenu](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.contextmenu.aspx) you can then call [ContextMenu.Show](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.contextmenu.show.aspx) with a position and it will show the context menu at that position.

So you could do that in your button click event. Or did you want to 'fake' taps on the menu buttons on the soft menu bar?